# document.getElementByID external or inline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have been trying to use the `document.getElementByID` to pull information from an HTML file from an external JS file and it does not seem to be working.  Does the `document.getElementByID` only work if it is inline with the HTML file or can it work properly on an external JS file?  The JS file is called upon within the HTML document properly because other functions are working.

Comment: It should work on both ways.. have you tried to find the object using jquery instead of document.getElementById to see if there's any difference?

Comment: Make sure you use getElementById (note the lowercase d on the end) and not getElementByID.

Comment: post your html along with how you are calling your js file

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Does the document.getElementByID only work if it is inline with the HTML file

No.

> can it work properly on an external JS file?

Yes.

You're probably calling `document.getElementById()` before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 19):

First off, make sure you're using `document.getElementById("xxx")`, not `document.getElementByID("xxx")` (note the difference in capitalization at the end).  Your question refers to `document.getElementByID("xxx")` so that could be the problem right here.

Second, you must make sure that the function is executed AFTER the relevant DOM items have been parsed by the browser.  If you are putting the `document.getElementById` in an external JS file that is loaded in the `<head>` section and is executed immediately after it loads, then the DOM will not yet be ready.

You have several options:

**1)** Place the external JS file `<script>` tags at the end of the body, right before the `</body>` tag.  This will not only load/display your page faster, but will guarentee that the DOM is parsed before anything in that JS file can run.

```
<body>
Your HTML here

<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
```

**2)** Since you have jQuery, put your immediately executed code inside of a `$(document).ready(fn)` block so that jQuery will hold back the execution until the DOM is ready.  If you do it this way, then you can put your code anywhere (including in the `<head>` section if you want).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put your page initialization code here
});
```

**3)** Put your code anywhere you want, but don't have any of it execute immediately.  Instead, put all your initialization code in an intialization function (let's call it `myPageInit()` that you call from:

```
$(document).ready(myPageInit);
```

**4)** Put your code anywhere you want, but don't have any of it execute immediately.  Instead, put all your initialization code in an intialization function (let's call it `myPageInit()` that you call from a script right before the `</body>` tag with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">myPageInit()</script>
```

Comment: i got two questions for you sir: 
1. why would the op ask to use `getElementById` if he has jquery? 2. why not `window.onload=function() {// Todo};` ?

Comment: `getElementById()` is actually a bit quicker than jQuery if all you want is a single DOM element.  I don't know why the OP isn't using jQuery.  As for your 2nd question, `window.onload()` occurs AFTER all images are loaded.  `$(document).ready()`occurs when the DOM is ready BEFORE all images are done loading so it occurs sooner and is better if you don't need to wait for all images to finish loading.

Comment: jquery's id selector is exactly `document.getElementById`, and about why not use jquery, well, me and my coworker are building websites from a template, he uses jquery and i do not. he's code for the sites is around 30kb (not including the jquery dependency) while mine is 15kb total.

Comment: @Dementic - just step through `var x = $("#yourid")` sometime in the debugger.  You will see it executing a lot more lines of code (including a regex match) than `var x = document.getElementById("yourid)` before it eventually calls `document.getElementById("yourid)` internally and it creates an object and returns that.  jQuery is very beneficial in many circumstances (particularly cross browser stuff or animation stuff), but it is not always the fastest way to do things when there is a direct equivalent in plain javascript.

Comment: @Dementic - In this simple test, `getElementById()` is 5-20x faster than jQuery: http://jsperf.com/jquery-vs-js99.

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to do this:

```
window.onload = function () {
 // document.getElementById() code here
}
```

Then your `document.getElementById()` would not execute until every element on the page has fully loaded.

Answer (score 2):

If you put the script in the `<head>` then the body hasn't loaded yet and so the elements aren't there.

Either defer the script by using jQuery's functions, or put the script at the end of the body.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "My First JavaScript";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>js in ts</title>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>JavaScript in Body</h2>

   <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be much better if you add here some explanation from your own, not just code, even it could solve the problem...