# How do you get an element by ID from an external HTML document using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to have a list of pre-made elements in a seperate HTML doc that I can add to my HTML page. I know I can create elements and then add them like so:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("div"));
```

But the child I want to append is an HTML element in another HTML document. So something like this:

```
<html>
    <!-- External doc -->
    <div id="ext">
    </div>
</html>
```

I want to add the `div` to the main document like this:

```
<html> <--Main document-->
    <head></head>
    <body></body>       

<script>
    document.body.appendChild("externalDocument".getElementById("ext")); 
</script>
</html>
```

How can I reference the external document and get the `div`?

Comment: you could try `AJAX` or create an `iframe` and specify the exact div with the id of that div _(if you have the access to modify the other html page)_

Comment: this might help as they were trying to do something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048025/document-getelementbyid-external-or-inline

Comment: You'll have to first answer the question of "how would a page in one tab even know about the existence of a page in another?" because there are massive security implications: should all the event handlers be copied over, for instance? What about its internal references to its parentNode, all the way up to the document and the window? What do you need the element copied _for_? (e.g. can you not just rebuild an identical object based on some sparse data you can get from your other page using postMessage), etc

Comment: So to prevent talking around, rather than about, the actual problem: what are you trying to _do_ that makes you think you need to copy elements from one document into another? Because right now I'm pretty sure this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I just want to create some html elements using html tags  (but not have them displayed--just to be used for later on). And then choose to add them later on using Javascript

Comment: In that case, don't try putting them in a new document. Put the HTML in the document they will ultimately be part of, and just have them hidden by default by giving them a class and using CSS to give them `display: none` . Then you can use JS to set their class or display style later to reveal them.

Comment: @AndrewKor then please [rewrite your question](/help/how-to-ask) to make it clear what you want to do, and what you thought of in this case, because what you thought of is not how most people would ever do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add loaclstorage div element it.Then you can call that lcoalstorage and use it

```
   <html>
  <body>
   <!-- External doc -->
   <div id="ext">
   </div>
  <script>
   var div_element = document.getElementById("ext");
    localStorage.element = Json.Stringfy(div_element);
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

then json.parse it and use like this

```
        <html> <--Main document-->
     <head></head>
      <body></body>       

      <script>
      var element = Json.Parse(localStorage.element);
      document.body.appendChild(element);
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how do you get this external HTML. So, I thought about the following:

```
var htmlString = '<html><div id="div1">content</div></html>';
var html = (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");
html.getElementById("div1").innerHTML; // content
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the pre-created HTML component then please go with template engines. There are mainly popular template engine available visit : https://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/templating-engines-9134396

They provide many other feature also such as make dynamic templates, supports loops, variable, json, conditions and much more ...